# Yet another web.py name collision

Tags: python, python-3.x, web.py

I'm trying to make a simple Hello World web page in Python 3.7.4 and web.py `0.40-dev1` (which is supposed to be compatible) and I'm running into

> AttributeError: module 'web' has no attribute 'applications'

error. I've googled enough to know that is a name collision, but for the love of God I can't trace it.

Here's the full code:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

application = web.applications(urls, globals())

class index:
    def GET(self):
        greeting = 'Hello world'
        return greeting

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run
```

And here's the full Python interpreter output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin\app.py", line 7, in <module>
    application = web.applications(urls, globals())
AttributeError: module 'web' has no attribute 'applications'
```

Comment: what is `applications()` supposed to do in the `web` module?

Comment: That was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of you I just install [`web.py`](http://webpy.org/) to test your code. It seems there is no `applications` in the `web.py`. If your want to check it just try the below example.

```py
>>> import web
>>> 
>>> `applications` in dir(web)
False
>>> `application` in dir(web)
True
```

So is should be `web.application`. Your first problem be solved, when you run it you'll get another error `RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration`. That problem is solved in [“RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration” every time I try to run app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51700960/6194097) question. It occurs because of `python 3.7.*` versions. There is something wrong with `0.40-dev1` version. You have two opetions.

1. Remove the `0.40-dev1` version and install the stable version from there master branch. Just uninstall by using this command `pip uninstall web.py==0.40-dev1` and run this command `pip install -e git+https://github.com/webpy/webpy.git#egg=webpy`. This will install the latest version from master branch. (This is worked for me)
2. Next one is update the `utils.py` in this way. Find it from from `Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\web\utils.py` (I try it from windows) and find the `line 526`. Then you'll see something like this`yield next(seq)` and surround it with `try-catch` statement in this way. (**Not Recommended**, instead of that make your own version by fork the relevant branch)

```py
def take(seq, n):
    for i in range(n):
        # yield next(seq)
        try:
            yield next(seq)
        except StopIteration:
            return
```

This will solved your problem. I added some extra context here because I want to see the output. I don't know much about this change, just took it from [“RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration” every time I try to run app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51700960/6194097) question.

Comment: If you need I can make a pull request to them (or you can do the same if you know about it). Then you can install your own version of `web.py` without change the file from `site-package`.

Comment: did you mean to use back-ticks in your first example?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mentioned about `back-ticks` and the `first example`? Did you edit `utils.py` with my suggestions?

Comment: @Kushan Gunasekera, I'm getting the same result. `0.40-dev1` and `0.40-dev0` raise same `RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration` error at the same place and `0.39` is incompatible with Python 3.7. Admittedly I'm uncomfortable getting involved with third party project on github considering I just started learning Python the other day.

Comment: No just wait @ADSMarko, I'll give you a solution, don't worry. Give me few minutes. Are you `windows` or `linux` user?

Comment: @Kushan Gunasekera, Windows 10 (if it makes any difference).

Comment: @ADSMarko same here, `Windows 10` with `Python 3.7.3`. I updated my answer and check the 1st solution or follow this. Please uninstall the current `web.py` version by running `pip uninstall web.py==0.40-dev1`. Then run this `pip install -e git+https://github.com/webpy/webpy.git#egg=webpy` command, that's it. Try it and let me know.

Comment: @Kushan Gunasekera, good news now Python gives no error message (actually no output at all), bad news now localhost:8080 gives `This site can’t be reached`. What parameters should I pass to Python interpreter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197441/discussion-between-kushan-gunasekera-and-adsmarko).

Answer (score 1):

Just took a quick look at the docs. It looks like the command you are looking for is `web.application` not `web.applications`. Note the absence of the s on applications.

Comment: OP has a variable with the same name.  although it will not collide in this case, it can lead to confusion.

Comment: It could potentially lead to some confusion. But he has not done a wild card import ```from web import *```, so the ```web``` prefix is always required. Personally this would avoid any confusion for me.

Comment: Yep, that solved that issue. Now I'm getting ‚RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration‚ from \web\utils.py. I guess I should ask that that question.

Comment: post a new question after you google the new problem.