# RunTimeError every time I load my webpage

Tags: python, css

today when I started coding my web page it worked properly, but suddenly my css file didn't work. My changes didn't update. After reading a bit, I read that I was supposed to clean my cache. I did so, and after that when I run my webpage and click on any button, I see the next output in my console:

```
127.0.0.1:50860 - - [22/Dec/2019 13:22:20] "HTTP/1.1 POST /check-login" - 200 OK
127.0.0.1:50861 - - [22/Dec/2019 13:22:20] "HTTP/1.1 GET /static/css/swap.css" - 304 Not Modified
RuntimeError('generator raised StopIteration')
127.0.0.1:50860 - - [22/Dec/2019 13:22:20] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 200 OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/web/httpserver.py", line 239, in __iter__
    raise StopIteration()
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cheroot/server.py", line 1280, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cheroot/server.py", line 1083, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cheroot/wsgi.py", line 145, in respond
    for chunk in filter(None, response):
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
127.0.0.1:50860 - - [22/Dec/2019 13:22:20] "HTTP/1.1 GET /static/css/swap.css" - 304 Not Modified
RuntimeError('generator raised StopIteration')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/web/httpserver.py", line 239, in __iter__
    raise StopIteration()
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cheroot/server.py", line 1280, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cheroot/server.py", line 1083, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cheroot/wsgi.py", line 145, in respond
    for chunk in filter(None, response):
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

My main file looks like this:

```
import web   
from Models import RegisterModel, LoginModel

web.config.debug = False

urls = (
    '/', 'home',
    '/login', 'login',
    '/register', 'register',
    '/postregistration', 'postRegistration',
    '/check-login', 'checkLogin',
    '/logout', 'logout'

)

TEMPLATE_PATH = './Views/Templates'
BASE_FILE = 'MainLayout'


app = web.application(urls, globals())

session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore("sessions"), initializer={'user': None})
session_data = session._initializer

render = web.template.render(TEMPLATE_PATH, base=BASE_FILE, globals={'session': session_data, 'current_user': session_data["user"]})
# Classes/Routes

class home:
    def GET(self):
        return render.home()

class login:
    def GET(self):
        return render.login()

class checkLogin:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()

        login_model = LoginModel.LoginModel()
        isCorrect = login_model.check_user(data)

        if isCorrect:
            session_data["user"]=isCorrect
            return isCorrect

        return "error"

class logout:
    def GET(self):
        session['user'] = None
        session_data['user'] = None
        session.kill()
        return "success"

class register:
    def GET(self):
        return render.register()

class postRegistration:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()

        reg_model = RegisterModel.RegisterModel()
        reg_model.insert_user(data)

        return data.username

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Let me know if you need further information about any file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700960/runtimeerror-generator-raised-stopiteration-every-time-i-try-to-run-app). In python 3.7, rule of StopIteration has changed.

> PEP 479 is enabled for all code in Python 3.7, meaning that
>   StopIteration exceptions raised directly or indirectly in coroutines
>   and generators are transformed into RuntimeError exceptions.

You would need to use try-except in the error place like above link.

**Edit**

In your code, it seems that css isn't changed so 304 Not modified raise StopIteration.

In `__iter__` function in ../site-packages/web/httpserver.py, you will find this part.

```
def __iter__(self):
    # ...
    try:
        path = self.translate_path(self.path)
        etag = '"%s"' % os.path.getmtime(path)
        client_etag = environ.get("HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH")
        self.send_header("ETag", etag)
        if etag == client_etag:
            self.send_response(304, "Not Modified")
            self.start_response(self.status, self.headers)
            return
    except OSError:
        pass  # Probably a 404
```

Add this at the bottom.

```
except StopIteration:
    return
```

or use `pass` instead of `return`. That will verbosely rewrite the same things.

Comment: Thanks, I see what is going on now, but I still don't know where I am supposed to add the exception handler. And I also do not understand why it worked without this error yesterday and not today.

Comment: I have add codes to my answer. Please try. About error you got today, search 304 Not Modified.