# Generator raised StopIteration in find_job_titles package

Tags: python

I am trying to run this code:

```
from find_job_titles import FinderAcora
finder=FinderAcora()
```

```
finder.findall('IT Audit & Governance')
```

But it gives me this error everytime:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/find_job_titles/__init__.py in longest_match(matches)
     48     """
---> 49     longest = next(matches)
     50 

StopIteration: 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
1 frames
<ipython-input-31-5b965ac3d7be> in <module>
----> 1 finder.findall('IT Audit & Governance')

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/find_job_titles/__init__.py in findall(self, string, use_longest)

     82                             else return all overlapping matches
     83         :returns: list of matches of type `Match`
---> 84         """
     85         return list(self.finditer(string, use_longest=use_longest))
     86 

RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

I tried using the suggestions from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700960/runtimeerror-generator-raised-stopiteration-every-time-i-try-to-run-app) but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does `finder.findall(u'IT Audit & Governance')`
work (as suggested [here](https://github.com/fluquid/find_job_titles#quickstart))?

Comment: which library is this? could be a bug?

Comment: This library has not been maintained for years, and does not work on Python 3.7 and up.